# json_encode returns false when dealing with multibyte substring

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, mbstring

I am using almost the latest version of php (**5.5.11**) and here is the problem. When I use `json_encode` of the part of the string, it returns false. In the beginning I was using `substr`, but then I realized that this is totally wrong when dealing with non-English strings. But even after I used `mb_substr` I still see that `json_encode` returns `false`:

```
$s = "に搭載されるようになると、その手軽さからJは急速に普及していく。、通信に関する標準を策定する国際団体インターナショナル";
$a = mb_substr($s, 0, 10);
```

As you see,

```
var_dump( json_encode([
    'd' => $a
]) );
```

returns `false`, and

```
var_dump( json_encode([
    'd' => $s
]) );
```

returns correct json.

When looking into [json_last_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), I see that this is due to `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. So the problem is that mb_substr gives me malformed characters.

When I look at `var_dump($a);` I see that it produces `string(10) "に搭載�"` (I assume that each Japanese char is 3 bytes, and that question mark is malformed char).

So how can I get a substring from the string in such a way, that I will not get a malformed string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pass the `utf-8` encoding as the fourth parameter of the [`mb_substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and you are good to go.

```
$a = mb_substr($s, 0, 10,'utf-8');
echo $a; // に搭載されるようにな
echo json_encode($a); // "\u306b\u642d\u8f09\u3055\u308c\u308b\u3088\u3046\u306b\u306a"
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0bhiiA)</kbd>

Comment: If that solved the problem, doesn't it imply your `mb_internal_encoding` is not set to 'utf-8'? Wouldn't correctly setting internal encoding be a better solution?